# ASP.Net MVC View Page Sequential drop down lists not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of transferring code from one project to another. While this code seems to work in the other project it is not working in the new one. I am not sure if i am missing something or not.

I have 3 drop-down lists that rely on the last drop-down to populate. Country, State, and city. While Country is independent.

UPDATE: Added Model

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
```

UPDATED: Here is the drop-down code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Country, Model.Countries, "---Select Country---", new { @class = "", @id = "ddlCountry" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select State---", new { @class = "", @id = "ddlState" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select City---", new { @class = "", @id = "ddlCity" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

UPDATED: My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#ddlCountry').change(function () {
        //debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/States/Add",
            data: { countryId: $('#ddlCountry').val() },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#ddlState').append('<option value="' + value.StateId + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#ddlState').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Cities/Add",
            data: { stateId: $('#ddlState').val() },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#ddlCity').append('<option value="' + value.CityId + '">' + value.CityName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATED: Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        try
        {
            GeneralEntities generalEntities = new GeneralEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> countryNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
            VendorViewModel casModel = new VendorViewModel();

            List<Countries> countries = generalEntities.Countries.ToList();
            countries.ForEach(x =>
            {
                countryNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CountryName, Value = x.CountryId.ToString() });
            });
            casModel.Countries = countryNames;

            return View(casModel);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
    //Get States --- Resides in the StatesController
    public JsonResult Add(string countryId)
    {
        int Id;
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);

        var states = from a in db.States where a.CountryId == Id select a;
        return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The list does not populate and while debugging in the console window it returns a 500 server error. Do i have a permission not set right? Or is there something i am missing from my code?

Thanks for your help..

UPDATE:
Stack Trace..

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.]

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command) +1642350
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command) +91
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) +274
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +119
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +65
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +170
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +43
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.<>c.<Reader>b__6_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +37

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +745
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1() +97
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +292
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0() +179
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +281
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption) +31
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption) +138
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() +342
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty(TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) +86
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item) +102
   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.States_099B6D7821CA994DC43D6B921B123F55DDD45CBE606FA44560F0517091322265.get_Countries2() +32

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +91
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +105
   System.Web.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] args) +168
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +461
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1324
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +127
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +1279
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember) +195
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +29
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9836613
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

UPDATE:
I tried adding this to my connection string read from another post. However it messes with my security token..

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

UPDATE: 
It appears i am not getting any error now, but still not populating the States List After Country is selected.. The problem i am having is understanding why the original worked in the other solution and not in this one...

UPDATE: Moving this to a new Question. It appears to be a script conflict!
The continuation of this can be found here:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/60386156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386156/c-sharp-asp-net-java-scripts-and-styling-conflicting-with-sequential-drop-down-s)

Comment: Can you share what's being passed over the wire using your browser's dev tools? It's a guess, but if `countryId` is empty/null, then `Convert.ToInt32` might be blowing up. If you set a breakpoint just inside your controller action `Add`, does it hit?

Comment: Yes i do get the id. However when it drops through with a breakpoint on return Json, States has an error that says "The function evaluation requires all threads to run" at that point i would think it would have the states. Console has this. jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 POST http://localhost:59890/States/Add 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Javascript has this - try {

// Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); The only difference between the two projects is i am using 3.4.1 in this and 3.3.1 in the original. Not sure if i am missing anything else or not..

Comment: meanwhile on the server side it is doing the query and getting the data - running profiler..

Comment: could you please post stack trace? Error Code 500 could be anything.

Comment: I do not get an error page. Is there a way to retrieve that in the console? Sorry for my confusion. I have elmah error i use but i do not have it implemented in this project yet. I may have to add that to get the error i need...

Comment: In network tab of Developer Tools, you can select the call that is failing (which will be highlighted in RED in chrome developer tools network tab) and navigate to Response pane and paste the content what you see there.

Comment: Will do that now. Elmah is reporting this - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: Per stack trace, You are trying to return states of types IQueryable to view. So, please convert that to List or Enumerable `var states = (from a in db.States where a.CountryId == Id select a).ToList(); `

Comment: Added that and now getting a different error.. Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent. Not sure why it is trying to redirect..

Comment: Could you please show us how you are invoking $('#ddlCountry').change event?

Comment: Thank you for updating the post. Could you please show us how you are invoking/triggering those change events?

Comment: Change event is when a country is selected. The script sees ddlCountry on change. Then when a state is selected it does the same with Id ddlState.

Comment: Can you change type as get instead of post in the ajax call?

Comment: Did not make a difference. I am getting the data back, i put debugger; in script under $.each and it loopes through the states. However the dropdown list is empty..

Comment: If states dropdown is empty, then perhaps your page is reloading and hence resetting to empty dropdown as specified in your view code `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select State---", new { @class = "", @id = "ddlState" })`.

Comment: What would cause it to reload? I mean if it is reloading it doesn't appear to be. Also i have this in a modal as well. Neither the page or the modal populate the list. But didn't think a modal would refresh..Also if it refreshed the country would be blank and it is not..

Answer (score 0):

can you try with add full server URL to the ajax call and add [HttpPost] add on the action method

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult Add(string countryId)
        {
            int Id;
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);

            var states = from a in db.States where a.CountryId == Id select a;
            return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: At this point adding HttpPost to this does nothing other than not throw an error, there is still no list populated..